# NET core webapi: Why am I getting a 404 with this specific API request?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this request

```
    [HttpPost("Authenticate/{deviceIdentifier}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<AuthorizedDoorsDto>>> Authenticate(Guid deviceIdentifier)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.Parse(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
        return Ok(await mainService.Authenticate(id, deviceIdentifier));
    }
```

I'm testing this with Postman and I'm sending this request:

```
https://localhost:5002/Main/Authenticate?deviceIdentifier=bd78209e-e3a0-4576-a17c-832838ce6495
```

but I'm getting a 404.

I've another requestin the same controller: this one

```
    //For debugging
    [HttpGet("GetAll")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Device>> GetAll()
    {
        Guid id = Guid.Parse(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
        return Ok(await mainService.GetDevice(id));
    }
```

and it's working fine. So I don't get what is wrong with the first one.

Comment: Do you test it in Postman with POST? If so, I believe the data should be be put in the message body, instead of in the QueryString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request returns 404 because the endpoint expects `deviceIdentifier` argument to be a **Path Parameter** instead of a **Query Parameter**.

In this case, you should either change the request url to `https://localhost:5002/Main/Authenticate/bd78209e-e3a0-4576-a17c-832838ce6495` or remove this argument from the route to `[HttpPost("Authenticate")]`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the {deviceIdentifier} Parameter from your request path

[HttpPost("Authenticate/{deviceIdentifier}")]